# Angular 2 call child selector from one child module into child module

Tags: angular, components, angular2-template, typescript2.0, angular2-modules

I have a directory structure of:

```
|-resources
   |-views
      |-Typescript
         |-App
            |-app.module.ts
            |-app.component.ts
|-Modules
   |-Core
      |-Assets
         |-Typescript
            |-core.module.ts
            |-core.component.ts
   |-Category
      |-Assets
         |-Typescript
            |-category.module.ts
            |-category.module.ts
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from '../../../../Modules/Core/Assets/Typescript/core.module';
import { CategoryModule } from '../../../../Modules/Category/Assets/Typescript/category.module ';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule,
        CategoryModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<app-main></app-main>`
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

**core.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CoreComponent } from './core.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        CoreComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        CoreComponent
    ]
})

export class CoreModule {
}
```

**core.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: `<category></category>`
})

export class CoreComponent {}
```

**category.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [ CategoryComponent ],
    exports: [ CategoryComponent ]
})

export class CategoryModule {}
```

**category.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'category',
    template: `This is a category.`
})

export class CategoryComponent {
}
```

**I want to call the `category selector` on `category.component.ts` from `core.component.ts` which is on same level as category i.e. child module of main `app.module`.**

**Is it possible to call a component that is not defined in another module by only adding the module to the parent module list?**

Edit:
I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'category' is not a known element:
1. If 'category' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 yeah getting the error that `'category' is not a known element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `CategoryComponent` has been used by `CoreModule`(which is independant module), it should be included in `imports` of `CoreComponent`. Otherwise `CoreModule` components would not be aware of `CategoryModule` components.

**Code**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CoreComponent } from './core.component';
import { CategoryModule } from 
              '../../../../Modules/Category/Assets/Typescript/category.module ';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CategoryModule //<-- add here
    ],
    declarations: [
        CoreComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        CoreComponent
    ]
})

export class CoreModule {
}
```

And CategoryModule isn't going to be used by `AppModule` then remove it from `AppModule` imports.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `core.module.ts` file to import `CategoryModule` :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CategoryModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        CoreComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        CoreComponent
    ]
})

export class CoreModule {
}
```

Comment: is there any other method than letting the core know about category ??? Like if it could be known from `app`??

Comment: no, there is no other method. you have to import `CategoryModule` inside `CoreModule` or you have to add `CategoryComponent` to declarations of `CoreModule`